# SQL Server Design Date Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, database-design

Background:

My DB need to store YYYY-MM-DD and HH:MM:SS data generated from a Machine. Data will be inserted every few minutes, **every day** will have **Thousands of** records

Questions:

Should I separate Date column into another table with DateID and DateName?

What about time? HH:MM:SS, should it be another table or just a column?

How about query performance?? Should I index Date and Time Column with FK?

What's the best practices for Date and Time stamp?

Comment: SQL server has a `datetime` datatype.  I would use that.  Index it if it will benefit your queries.

Comment: You do not need to store YYYY-MM_DD or HH:MM:SS you need to store a date and a time (preferably as a DateTime). What do you mean by DateName?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I concern should I index Date Column???? because data is inserted in every few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't treat date/time as the index into this data.  Treat date/time as a single fact about the data.  Therefore you don't want to separate out the date or time into a separate table.  You don't need to store a "date name" because there are intrinsic functions that can convert a `datetime` column into any given date or time format that you might need.  It is important to use the SQL `datetime` data type to record this fact data because SQL Server gives you lots of tools to work with this data type.

Regarding indexing, this is important for retrieving your transactional data.  Your date/time column can be indexed and probably should be, if you plan on filtering by date and time.  The same would be true if you plan on ordering your data by date when you select it.

Comment: Thanks @Joel Brown But my concern is data will be insert every few minutes, and Index is only good for SELECT, how much would it impact on query performance if Index Date??

Comment: @user3479682 - If you are inserting in chronological order, which seems pretty likely, then having an index for the insert won't be an issue.  If you were inserting thousands of records per minute then that might be worth testing for optimization.  Inserting every minute is not going to be a performance concern.  The positive impact on your SELECT statements will very likely be well worth it.  (I say "very likely" since I don't know what your SELECT statements look like.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, so index SmallDateTime type seems worthy? SELECT cmd may only happen few times a week by 4 users, and just select on different date or date range to view about 12 Columns data. SO SELECT is not frequent event, still worth a try for index???

Comment: SmallDateTime is probably more than good enough for your needs unless you need sub-second precision.  You can always try it without an index and build the index later if you want to see whether it helps in practice.  You don't have to have the index built before data is inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your aditional data you are going to save into the table. If you have data which are always the same on one day you shoud create a second table for the day. You can use the time as primary key.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I concern should I index Date Column???? because data is inserted in every few minutes but user may select thousands of data in one query. What should I choose??